# Unlinked subreport is creating duplicate records in the main crystal report

Tags: duplicates, crystal-reports, report, subreport

I have an **unlinked** subreport in the report footer of the main report but for each record in this subreport, the records of the main report is getting duplicated. As it is an unlinked subreport, this should not happen. Could anyone tell what can be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

Subreports cannot impact record selection for main reports.
You can verify by removing the subreport.

Most likely, the record duplication is caused by the table joins in the main report data source definition.

Comment: Yes, I know subreport should not alter record selection in the main report. But I checked if I have one record in the subreport. The main report is getting printed as expected but if I have two or more records, the records in the main report is getting repeated exactly the same number of times. As I mentioned it is an unlinked report but I'm thinking probably I have missed something. Any suggestions?

Comment: As suggested in my answer, look at your table join logic in the main report.
Most likely a table used in the subreport is also present in the main report. Check the join logic.